# Increase performance of timeinterval calculation

Tags: c#, performance, datetime

I have the code fragment below (short version first, compete version after) which loops over lots of records which are in chronological order. The number of records ranges from 100's of thousands to millions. I need to compare the time interval between successive records and determine the difference in minutes to decide on some action and set a value. This is the performance bottleneck of the whole application so I need to do something. The profiler clearly shows that

```
(DayList[nextIndex].ThisDate - entry.ThisDate).Minutes
```

is the bottleneck of the bottleneck. When this is solved, the next bottleneck will be the date call in the DayList creation:

```
List<MonthfileValue> DayList = thisList.Where(x => x.ThisDate.Date == i.Date).ToList();
```

Those two lines roughly take 60% - 70% of all CPU.

So the question is: how can I increase performance (dramatically) or should I abandon this road completely (because this performance is unacceptable)?

```
for ( DateTime i=startdate; i<=enddate; i=i.AddDays(1) )
  {
    int nextIndex = 0;

    List<MonthfileValue> DayList = thisList.Where(x => x.ThisDate.Date == i.Date).ToList(); 

    foreach (MonthfileValue entry in DayList)
    {
      if (++nextIndex < DayList.Count - 1)
      {
        IntervalInMinutes = (DayList[nextIndex].ThisDate - entry.ThisDate).Minutes;

      }
      // do some calculations
    }
    // do some calculations
  }
```

The complete version is below:

```
  for ( DateTime i=startdate; i<=enddate; i=i.AddDays(1) )
  {
    int nextIndex = 0;

    DaySolarValues tmp = new DaySolarValues();
    List<MonthfileValue> DayList = thisList.Where(x => x.ThisDate.Date == i.Date).ToList(); 

    foreach (MonthfileValue entry in DayList)
    {
      if (++nextIndex < DayList.Count - 1)
      {
        OldIntervalInMinutes = IntervalInMinutes;
        IntervalInMinutes = (DayList[nextIndex].ThisDate - entry.ThisDate).Minutes;

        if (IntervalInMinutes > 30)
        {
          IntervalInMinutes = OldIntervalInMinutes; //reset the value and try again
          continue;  // If more than 30 minutes, then skip this data
        }
        else if (IntervalInMinutes != OldIntervalInMinutes)
        {
           // Log some message and continue
        }
      }

      tmp.SolarHours += entry.SolarRad / entry.SolarTheoreticalMax >= SunThreshold ? IntervalInMinutes : 0;
      tmp.SolarEnergy += entry.SolarRad * IntervalInMinutes * 60;  
      tmp.SunUpTimeInMinutes += IntervalInMinutes;
    }

    tmp.SolarHours /= 60; 
    tmp.SolarEnergy /= 3600;   
    tmp.ThisDate = i;

    DailySolarValuesList.Add(tmp);
  }
```

Comment: Just use the proper data structure (hash map)?

Comment: I don't get your point

Comment: The `DayList` is created for every loop of `for ( DateTime i=startdate; i<=enddate; i=i.AddDays(1) )` but this list itself nor any entry is changed in the whole code. Move that creation out of the outer loop to avoid creating the same list multiple times.

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question that seems unrelated to the `TimeSpan`-calculation performance problem. Could you simplify your code by removing all unrelated noise, and leaving the absolute minimal that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Aha... maybe it is the chosen name for the  list, but this list changes for every date and contains all (interval) records for that day. And for every record I need to determine the time interval for the time recorded for that record.

Comment: To me it seems that the code in the line `(DayList[nextIndex].ThisDate - entry.ThisDate).Minutes` should not be slow in it self. I think that the calculation should be quite fast. The problem is probably that it is run a lot of times. If possible you should try to fix your algorithm so that this line is not run that many times. It would be easier to help fixing your algorithm if you described in simple terms what your program is supposed to do.

Comment: Btw having a variable `DateTime i` is really confusing. Like having a variable `int date` or `string number`. This naming scheme may be great for job-security, but not great for any other purpose.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: modified the question. You remark abou the i is OK but I'll leave it as is, it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @mortb: I need to check for every record if the interval is still the same. It is a kind of variable interval integration which is executed where the interval is determined by the recorded timesteps. So the algorithm can not remove the recorded times but has to calculate the difference in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can clearly see that the `Where(...)` call steals performance.
For me it would be the first step to try this:

```
var dayLookup = thisList.ToLookup(x => x.ThisDate.Date);

for ( DateTime currentDate =startdate; currentDate <=enddate; currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1) )
  {
    int nextIndex = 0;

    List<MonthfileValue> DayList = dayLookup[currentDate];

    ...
  }
```

This way you create a hash lookup before the loop, so getting the `DayList` will be a less expensive operation

Comment: Only this change led to a performance improvement of roughly 70% (I went from 100 seconds to 25 seconds for my test dataset. Thank you!!

Do you think the time difference could be improved [this dramatically] as well? Eye opening btw !

Comment: And I can add that the time difference does not have that large an influence. The bottlenecks are elsewhere but much smaller. So basically my problem is solved.
Thank you.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the question gets -2?

Comment: Some users can be very picky about questions that they are not able to understand the first time they read it (quickly) and want posters to make put an effort into reducing their problem as much as possible. Personally I understand that, when your stuck on a problem, it is not always that easy to create a perfect question.

Comment: @HansRottier  Isn't your posted profiling information terribly wrong? If the sum of the first-bottleneck and the second-bottleneck is "60-70%", how can solving the second-bottleneck speeds it up by 75%?

Comment: @HansRottier About the down votes -- another possible reason may be that you just post an incomplete snippet of the code, leaving several variables undefined. Usually you can just generate random values for `thisList`, `startdate` and `enddate`. See [mcve].

Comment: @user202729 1) about the profiling - my bad, that over-enthousiastic estimate of 70% was too large because I had taken out some calculations, having my original calc back gave a speed up of 50% very good and indeed more  in line with the profiler. Apparently the other btlnck was not that serious. 2) on the down votes - you say it is an incomplete example, another asks to strip it down more. I did not give a runnable code snippet, I assumed what I supplied would be sufficient. I have seen much more dubious questions without this depreciation.

Comment: @mortb: the actual working solution required a modification: `List<MonthfileValue> DayList = (List<MonthfileValue>)dayLookup[currentDate].ToList();` The strange thing was the compiler did not give a message without the ".ToList()". I thought that surprising.

Comment: @HansRottier They're not contradictory. -- That assumption is dangerous, although in this particular case it's correct. A reproducible example should always be posted.

Comment: If your code is still slow, you can try to convert the outer `for` loop into `Parallel.For` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop You will then need to use a thread safe list for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netcore-3.1 as type for `DailySolarValuesList`.

Comment: @HansRottier regarding the `.ToList()` comment. Here is an article about the difference between something that is `IEnumerable<T>` and a `IList<T>`. Calling  `ToList()` will turn any `IEnumerable<T>` (even something that is already an `IList<T>`) into an `IList<T>`. You need to understand this

Comment: Thanks for both comments (on parallelism and the .ToList explanation). Missing link  though, but I'll search/find Those are fields I only vaguely looked at so far. If parallelism improves significantly I'll report back.

Comment: @mortb I did the test on parallelism and it technically worked fine but the order of the list (on the foreach) must be maintained so it is a bit more complex (and interesting). The same holds for the outer for loop. So doing parallel quickly does not work, but it definitely is a track I am going to investigate further. Thanks for the  inspiring responses!